# composition of ADR in comparison to home market

Tags: united-states, stocks, india, financial-literacy, adr

I want to know how one unit of ADR is constructed from the home stock.

For example, I see a [ADR](https://www.google.com/search?q=NYSE:%20TTM&tbm=fin) for [India's Tata motors](https://www.google.com/search?q=BOM:%20500570&tbm=fin) . ADR is trading at about $12 and in home market it is about INR 177, but given the conversion of INR [71](https://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount=1&From=USD&To=INR) to USD 1, one Indian stock should be selling for about $2.50, but it is for $12, so there has to be more than one Indian stock in one unit of ADR.

Where can I find that conversion and is that conversion a standard ?

Comment: http://www.adr.com

Comment: https://www.adr.com/drprofile/876568502

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @SSpring in comments [adr.com](https://www.adr.com/drprofile/876568502), which is owned by Morgan Stanley so relatively reputable, states that the multiplier is 5:

> Ratio (DR/underlying)1 : 5

this means the ratio of the DR (depositary receipt) to the underlying (the Indian Tata Motors shares) is 1:5. This fits with your analysis since 5 * $2.5 is approximately $12. The "approximately" is probably a result of rounding differences.

[image: Result from https://www.adr.com/drprofile/876568502]